# FOR Loop -only giving result for 1st iteration in function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, user-defined-functions

FOR loop is only giving result for first iteration then it stops and doesn't show any error also,
while finding median of pandas.dataframe

```
def construct_frame(x):
    
    '''constructor function to get median of any data'''

    if x.shape[1]>=0:
        for i in range(1,(x.shape[1])):
            print(i)
            x_ser = x.iloc[:,i].sort_values(ignore_index=True)                 #sorting values in descending order

            x_ser_new= pd.Series(x_ser)

    #             print(x_ser)
    #             print(len(x_ser))
    #             print(type(x_ser))
    #             print(x_ser.dtypes)
    #             print(x_ser.shape[0])


            if len(x_ser_new)% 2==0:                                       #checking length of data if 'even'

                res = (x_ser_new[len(x_ser_new)//2]+ x_ser_new[(len(x_ser_new)//2)-1])/2   # nth column and (n-1)th column average
                return res 

            else:                                                      # if length of data is 'odd'

                res = x_ser_new[len(x_ser_new)//2]                             # nth column 

                return res



construct_frame(df)
```

result should be for 10 columns but shows only 1st column median result:

1
34.26

Answer (score 1):

Don't return `res` inside the loop otherwise it breaks the loop on the first iteration:

```
def construct_frame(x):
    
    '''constructor function to get median of any data'''

    median = {}  # HERE
    if x.shape[1]>=0:
        for i in range(1,(x.shape[1])):
            x_ser = x.iloc[:,i].sort_values(ignore_index=True)
            x_ser_new = pd.Series(x_ser)

            if len(x_ser_new)% 2==0:
                res = (x_ser_new[len(x_ser_new)//2]+ x_ser_new[(len(x_ser_new)//2)-1])/2
            else:
                res = x_ser_new[len(x_ser_new)//2]
            median[x_ser.name] = res  # HERE
    return pd.Series(median, name='median')  # HERE
```

Output:

```
>>> construct_frame(df)
Rank        2.0
Category      C
Name: median, dtype: object
```

A faster method:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, 1:].quantile(0.5, numeric_only=False, interpolation='lower')
Rank        2.0
Category      C
Name: 0.5, dtype: object
```

Comment: getting error while passing dataframe in function as - construct_frame(df)

Comment: I don't understand why you have this error. It works perfectly with any data. Did you try the faster method?